# Eclipse and GTK+ 3.0 development in C/C++ Autocompletion

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gtk, gtk3

I am trying for hours now to find what on earth do I have to do in order to make Eclipse show proposals for the GTK+ 3.0 functions in C/C++. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I mean on Netbeans I didn't do anything at all and it automatically gave me autocomplete suggestions with a little documentation.All I did is to insert the source file and the Makefile. In Eclipse  haven't managed to add the Makefile that I made myself but I opened a new project with the source file only. Also I installed `pkg-config` but there was no luck with it for what I am asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The information is extracted from [this blog post](http://neptunecentury.blogspot.co.at/2013/09/linux-create-gui-application-in-c-using.html):

You need to add the following paths to the "Includes" for the cross G++ compiler:

```
 /usr/include/glib-2.0
 /usr/include/gtk-2.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The problem is now after I did all this it gives an error during compilation that says: fatal error: pango/pango.h: No such file or directory. I already included /usr/include/pango-1.0/pango/

Comment: Try just /usr/include/pango-1.0

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.